# Select random row for each group in a postgres table

Tags: sql, postgresql, window-functions

I have a table that is roughly:

```
id | category | link | caption | image
```

My goal is to fetch a random row from each distinct category in the table, for all the categories in the table. The plan is to then assign each row to a variable for its respective category.

Right now I'm using multiple SELECT statements resembling:

```
SELECT link, caption, image FROM table
       WHERE category='whatever'
       ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1`
```

But this seems inelegant and creates more trips to the DB, which is expensive.

I'm pretty sure there's a way to do this with window functions in Postgres, but I have no experience with them and I'm not entirely sure how to use one to get what I want.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Try something like:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (category) *
FROM table 
ORDER BY category, random();
```

Or with window functions:

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
SELECT *, row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY category ORDER BY random()) as rn
FROM table ) sub
WHERE rn = 1;
```

Comment: Excellent! Both of those seem to work for my purposes. Thank you!